# How to make custom share via screen in android

Tags: android, android-sharing

My app has one share feature. So while click on share it should show the list of apps to be shared with. Right now I am using this code

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

and it is showing the dialog like this

[image]

But what I need is , I need to show the share dialog like a grid view like this. Is it possible to do so? How can I customize the share dialog window

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you have to create custom dialog for that. put this listview in some dialog.

refer this :

https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet

use this code to get available items of ACTION_SEND

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
List<ResolveInfo> listGel = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(galleryIntent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo res : listGel) {
    Log.e("package",res.activityInfo.packageName);
    Log.e("name",res.activityInfo.name);
    Log.e("proname",res.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()).toString());


}
```

and as other option of bottomSheet you can have custom listview also, which will popup from bottom of screen.

Comment: Is there any supporting library available for bottom sheets to support older versions?

Comment: if you want to give support to older version, please try second option, have listview/gridview and give it animation to open from bottom. you have to handle it manualy

Comment: Ok. in that way do I need to handle the click action manually?

Comment: yes. everything, you need to save package name of all application and then call respective application on click of list/grid

Comment: can u pls give me one sample? for eg: on clicking on messaging app , I need to open messaging app with my text to be shared.