# Customise Sharing Intent Dialog Is That Possible?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Code For Opening Sharing Intent

```
String xtype = "image/*";
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType(xtype);
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", new File(tmpImageUri.getPath()));
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share via"));
```

it shows sharing intent dialog like this

[image: Default Share Intent]

But now I want it like this

[image: I want Like Sharing Intent]

Is that Possible to customise Sharing Intent Dialog ?

Comment: Yes you can, check [get-list-of-applications-which-can-share-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37704682/get-list-of-applications-which-can-share-data), you will get a list of applications and after that use it in whatever way you want to

Comment: @RaviRupareliya Thank you for response sir but dont wont to list of application that aacept image's i want to customise sharing intent dialog any idea how i can achive this

Comment: With this code you will get all the application which can share data, use that list in your customized list, that's it.

Comment: @RaviRupareliya its good idea thanks for such this kind of help

Comment: no idea who want to close this question with down vote please leave appropriate comment before downvote

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32202955/10372900). This might be helpful.

Comment: @itsmysterybox thank you for your response but i dont want to use library's......

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki What about [bottom sheets](https://material.io/design/components/sheets-bottom.html)

Comment: @itsmysterybox good idea

Comment: @itsmysterybox what's about dialogbox with listview ?

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki Great! Implement it now :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to create custom sharing dialog. You just need to get the `IntentActivity` list and customize as per your requirement. For Sample you can do as below.

> Step 1: Prepare Intent

```
String urlToShare = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yourapp.packagename";
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
// intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "If any extra"); // NB: has no effect!
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Let me recommend you this application \n\n" + urlToShare);
```

> Step 2: Get activity list and set in [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter).

```
final List<ResolveInfo> activities = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

List<DialogItem> appNames = new ArrayList<DialogItem>();

    for (ResolveInfo info : activities) {
            appNames.add(new DialogItem(info.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString(),
                    info.loadIcon(getPackageManager())));
    }
final List<DialogItem> newItem = appNames;
ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<DialogItem>(activity,
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, android.R.id.text1, newItem) {
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                //Use super class to create the View
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView tv = v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                tv.setText(newItem.get(position).app);
                tv.setTextSize(15.0f);
                //Put the image on the TextView
                tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(newItem.get(position).icon, null, null, null);

                //Add margin between image and text (support various screen densities)
                int dp5 = (int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
                tv.setCompoundDrawablePadding(dp5);

                return v;
            }
};
```

**Note:-** Make sure that `DialogItem` is your model class and you have to create in you app.

```
public class DialogItem {
    public String app = "";
    public Drawable icon;

    public DialogItem(String name, Drawable drawable) {
        app = name;
        icon = drawable;
    }
}
```

> Step 3: Set that adapter in your AlertDialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setTitle("Custom Sharing Dialog");
        builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                ResolveInfo info = activities.get(item);

                if (info.activityInfo.packageName.equals("com.facebook.katana")) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Facebook Selected ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {

                    // start the selected activity
                    Log.i(TAG, "Hi..hello. Intent is selected");
                    intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```

**Output :-**

[image]

Its custom sharable dialog using [AlertDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog) but you can do all setting(UI,Selection,Theme,etc) as per your requirement by using custom layout and creating [Dialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog) class